# Can I take a reference of a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I am passing in a **reference to a pointer variable** into a function. The function will do something and point the pointer variable to some object. Code:

```cpp
int Foo(Obj* &ptr) {
  // do something...
  ptr = some_address;
  return return_value;
}

int main() {
  Obj* p = nullptr;
  int ret = Foo(p);
  // do something with ret
  p->DoSomething();
}
```

However, things get trickier if I want to pass a reference to a **pointer to const**. I would like the pointer variable itself to be changed (hence the reference), but I don't want the pointed `Obj` instance to change using this pointer. In my imagination, it should be something like:

```cpp
int Foo(const Obj* &ptr) {
  // do something...
  ptr = some_address;
  return return_value;
}

int main() {
  const Obj* p = nullptr;
  int ret = Foo(p);
  // do something with ret
  p->DoSomething(); // this should only work when DoSomething() is const method
}
```

**EDIT: the following error cannot be reproduced and is hence deleted. This question is focused on the concept of reference-of-pointer instead of solving an issue**

> C++ gives this compile error:
>
> ```
> main.cpp:22:10: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const Obj*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const Obj*’
>    22 |     Foo(ptr);
>       |         ^~~
> main.cpp:14:23: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void test(const Obj*&)’
>    14 | int Foo(const Obj* &ptr) {
>       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
> ```

Some thoughts:

**Error cannot be reproduced**

> 1. I believe this error is shown when I am trying to pass in an "unnamed variable" into a reference parameter. In this case I am passing the variable `ptr`, which shouldn't be an issue.

2. `ptr` is passed in as a parameter because the function has a useful return value. Setting `ptr` is more like a side-product of this function, where the caller can choose to ignore or use.
3. I can also try using `Obj**` as the parameter, which is passing by pointer instead of passing by reference. This works when a `const Obj**` is passed as parameter. I am just wondering what will be the case if the parameter is passed by reference.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Also, your error messages do not match your code example.  The error mentions a function named `test` being called on line 14 of main.cpp, but that is a clearly a different program to what you've shown.

Comment: The error message lists the erroneous code as `Foo(ptr)`...  The code given is not the code that produced the error message.   What is the exact type of  `ptr` ??

Comment: That code, with a trivial implementation of `Obj` added, does not produce that error.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The test function I named was `test` instead of `Foo`. I replaced `test` to `Foo` after copying the compile error to SO, and made a mistake...

Comment: As for the compiler, I originally compiled my code using both clang++ and this [online GDB testing](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler). However I cannot reproduce this error (???) in both environment now... I am editing this question into one without the error.

Comment: With the error removed, what exactly is the question? You have a goal, you implemented your goal, and it works now. You end with some thoughts, but no question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is, as the error code given does not match your code.

Your second example with `int Foo(const Obj* &ptr)` works exactly as intended, and compiles fine if you make `DoSomething`const.

To comment your three thoughts:

1. If you const things correctly, the error goes away.
2. I really, really dislike such out-paramteres. It is much cleaner to return a struct or a pair of int and pointer. That way the caller can write `const auto[ret, p] = Foo();` and not have to explicitely declare the pointer that you may not want to use.
3. Passing pointers to pointers is C-style, due to lack of references, and just make the code harder to read, with no benefit.

Below is slightly modified code that compiles fine, with a better Foo too, as mentioned in my answer to 2.:

```
#include <utility>

struct Obj
{
    void DoSomething() const;
};

// This is ugly of course, used just to have a valid ptr to return
Obj global;

int Foo(const Obj* &ptr) {
  // do something...
  ptr = &global;
  return 5;
}

std::pair<int, const Obj*> BetterFoo()
 {
  // do something...
  return {5, &global};
}

int main() {

  const Obj* p1 = nullptr;
  int ret1 = Foo(p1);

  const auto[ret2, p2] = BetterFoo();

  p1->DoSomething(); 
  p2->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: *"I am not sure what your problem is"* -- this is typically a reason to avoid answering and instead request more information via a comment (or upvote such a comment if one already exists -- which is what I did). The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of questions and answers for future visitors. If a problem is not clearly identified in the question, it is unlikely that future visitors will be able to tell if the question relates to them.

Answer (score -2):

One way to deal with this situation is to use `typedef` or `using`. For example, `using ObjPtr = Obj*;` now the function would be `int Foo(const ObjPtr& ptr) { ... }`.

Comment: `const ObjPtr` is not the same as `const Obj *`. The former is a constant pointer to a non-constant object, while the latter is a non-constant pointer to a constant object. The OP specifically requested a pointer-to-const, which `ObjPtr` fails to deliver.

Comment: As @JaMiT wrote, by doing this, you make the pointer itself const - which means that it is impossible to reassign the pointer inside Foo. So with your "solution", the Foo function will no longer compile.